# white space in journal's style file

Tags: templates

I need to compile an article for publication in a journal. I have used their style file, but was rejected for having a large white space on the second page. However it seems that the white space is the fault of the style file: it seems to happen whenever an article has a lot of front matter.

Here's the style file (endm.cls):
http://www.pastebin.ca/raw/3044760

Here's a small example demonstrating the desired behaviour:
http://www.pastebin.ca/raw/3044776
[image]

Here's an example demonstrating the problem (all I have done is added some extra text to the abstract):
http:// www.pastebin.ca/raw/3044772
[image]

Can anyone come up with some way to fix the problem? I've tried using negative \vspace commands but that seems to mess up the alignment of everything in the front matter

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: What white space are they referring to? And exactly which pages are you showing here?

Comment: I'm referring to the white space directly below the abstract. In the pictures I'm showing the end of the abstract and what is directly below (in the first picture, the first section, but in the second picture, a whole page of white space).

Comment: Please don't use external links (unless you are planning to maintain them forever, so later readers can follow this site) make the example small enough to add inline to the question, in a code block (`{}` in the editor)

Comment: In my opinion, the journal is responsible for the correct output and they should take care of this. It should not be the author to fix their stuff.

Comment: It is the fault of the style. It has a `\newpage` in `\close@fm`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Although pasetebin links can expire, these are configured to persist forever. I think it's better this way, to reduce them to a minimal example would mean removing standard parts of an article, and modifying the fixed ENDM style file.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I absolutely agree, but I was told by an Elsevier employee that this journal has the "camera ready copy workflow" and they are not authorized to make changes to my submission

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Perfect, that totally fixed the problem. I'm not supposed to be allowed to edit the style file, but in this case it looks like I have little choice. But I'm afraid I don't seem have sufficient reputation to upvote you

Comment: @Matt linking off site is against the site guidelines and many people won't follow such links so you greatly reduce your chance of getting an answer, but it's your question so it's up to you. You should _anyway_ make the example minimal to help anyone offering to help who has to trace the code.

Comment: Please tell the journal guys to fix up their stuff.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to add an answer to this question?

Answer (score 3):

It is the fault of the style. It has a `\newpage` in `\close@fm`.